# Why my bike gear won't change only when I stop pedaling?

Tags: gears, pedals, city

I have an issue with my bike, it works nicely until I am changing the gears. Every time I want to change one gear up, I have to stop pedaling or it won't change. There is no issue going back one gear.

Comment: Does 'up' gears mean 'bike goes faster with less turns of the pedal' or the opposite?

Comment: What kind of shifting mechanism do you have? Do you have cogs in the rear and chain shifting from one cog to another? Or something inside the hub? A photo or bike type description would help.

Comment: @john I'd guess that OP means "make the chain go from a smaller to a larger cog"  (which is technically changing "down" to a lower gear - yay for jargon)    Suspicion is based on changing the other way being "no issue"   But ciocaion needs to confirm that.

Answer (score 5):

Do you have the gears inside the hub? (I see city bike tag)

If so, the mechanism of the gear change requires that you ease the pressure from the pedals (or stop pedalling) or it won't be able to shift. That's normal!

However,

If it is a derailleur system, heavily worn drivetrains or derailleurs with weakened springs can need that pause in your pedalling to help the shift (the extra time and lack of force through the chain can help the derailleur when it's at EOL) but it's a bad sign in this case, that some (major) overhaul is required.